# How can I read the padlock data visible in intellisense when mouse hovering?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm guessing this data with the padlock is read-only, but how can I read the data?

[image: Picture of data from mouse hover]

I'm using visual studio 2015 and the object is of type SshClient.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Thanks.

Comment: You should describe what's happening/what you're seeing for those who can't see that picture. Right now you have a description of where the image came from instead of what's *in* the image. More generally, your question should be clear and answerable without going to 3rd party links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this padlock means that the field is private/internal not readonly and you cannot access it directly.

What you can do to access value stored in it is you can use `Reflection` :

```
string nameOfTheVariableYouWantToAccess = "_encoding";
Type objType = objectYouWantToGetValueFrom.GetType();
FieldInfo fieldInfo = objType.GetField(nameOfTheVariableYouWantToAccess, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
object valueOfTheVariable = fieldInfo.GetValue(objectYouWantToGetValueFrom);
```